# how to solve Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
    <form action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter 
    Your Password" required>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<%=user_id%> ">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
    </form>"

// routes 
user_route.post('/forget-password', userController.resetPassword);

//controllers
const resetPassword = async(req,res)=>{
try {
    const user_id = req.body.user_id;
    const password = req.body.password;

    const secure_password = await securePassword(password);

    const updatedData  = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id:user_id }, { $set:{ password:secure_password, token:""}});

         res.redirect("/");

} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
}
```

}
Output
Server is connected at port 3000
Connection Succesful
Email has been sent:- 250 2.0.0 OK  1661801316 i2-
20020a170902c94200b00174f7d107c8sm1521208pla.293 - gsmtp
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: '630ce985474a211c98fe80c2 ' }" (type Object)
at path "_id" for model "User"

Answer (score 0):

This line is problematic:

```
const updatedData  = await User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id:user_id }, { $set:{ password:secure_password, token:""}});
```

the function `findByIdAndUpdate` take the _id as the first argument ([document here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate)). You're passing an object `{_id: user_id}`, hence the error.

It should be:

```
const updatedData  = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, { $set:{ password:secure_password, token:""}});
```

Comment: It is again showing the same problem Cast to ObjectId failed for value "630b010239a5335634cc7b10 " (type string) at path "_id" for model "User".

Comment: You have an extra space at the end of the string. Try removing it.

Comment: It again shows the same thing Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: ' 630ce985474a211c98fe80c2' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "User".